# Cyrillic Characters RSS PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write a RSS feed for a website which mostly  has Russian articles, though sometimes English. The site is built with php mysql.
 This is what the text looks like when I visit the url:

> Áåñåäà ¹1 èç öèêëà "Èçðàèëü è ìû"

What am I doing wrong?
Also, I'm tryn to add this line of code on top of the document but it breaks it and I get an error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Here is my php code excluding the database connect info.
I'm desperate. Please help.

```
<?php
require_once ('cutils/db_connect.php3');
// PHP file that renders perfect Dynamic XML for MySQL Database result sets
// Script written by Adam Khoury @ www.developphp.com - April 05, 2010
// View the video that is tied to this script for maximum understanding
// -------------------------------------------------------------------
header("Content-Type: rss-http;"); //set the content type to xml
// Initialize the xmlOutput variable

$xmlBody = '
<rss version="2.0">

<channel>
<title>Name of your site</title>
<description>A description of your site</description>
<link>http://yoururl.com/</link>
<copyright>Your copyright information</copyright>';
// Connect to your MySQL database whatever way you like to here
mysql_connect("localhost","dbuser","dbpass") or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("sinaius2_em") or die ("no database");
// Execute the Query on the database to select items(20 in this example)
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `title`, `article_text`, `article_date` FROM `articles`ORDER BY `article_date` DESC LIMIT 0 , 15");
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    // Set DB variables into local variables for easier use 
    $id = $row["id"]; 
    $title = $row["title"] ;  
    $date_time = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["article_date"])); 
    $description = $row["article_text"];  
    // Start filling the $xmlBody variable with looping content here inside the while loop 
    // It will loop through 20 items from the database and render into XML format
    $xmlBody .= "
<item> 
    <title>$title</title>
    <description>TEST</description>  
    <pubDate>$date_time</pubDate>
    <link>http://www.evreimir.com/article.php?id=$id</link> 
</item> ";
} // End while loop
mysql_close(); // close the mysql database connection_aborted
$xmlBody .= "</channel>
</rss>";
echo $xmlBody; // output the gallery data as XML file for flash
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can (and probably should) include the charset in your `Content-Type` header.  Also, I've never seen the content type `rss-http`, I'd use either `text/xml` or `application/xml`.  There also a few more specific content types, but [there might be some issues with this](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/381.cfm).  RSS *is* xml, so either generic xml content type will work fine.

```
header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1");
```

`ISO-8859` does include Cyrillic characters, but that *may* not be the charset your data is stored in [here is a reference for various other Cyrillic charsets that are in-use](http://czyborra.com/charsets/cyrillic.html).  In any case, you should probably specify the same encoding that you're using in your mysql database.  You can use `show create table your_table_name` in mysql to see what the charset is for a given table (or for an individual column in the table).

Also... the description field in RSS will be handled as HTML *after* the user agent extracts if from the XML document.  For this reason, I *strongly* suggest that you wrap the content of your item description as CDATA.  Even so, you'll still need to entity encode things that you would normally entity encode in HTML text (like a "less-than" symbol that's not part of an html tag).  [Here's a good example page](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/encodingDescriptions.html).

```
<description><![CDATA[(5 &lt; 8) is math, but <b>this is bold text</b>]]></description>
```

Notice how the HTML `<b>` tags don't need encoding because they're inside the CDATA, but the less-than symbol gets encoded anyway to escape it within the other HTML tags in the CDATA description.  Without the CDATA, you'd need to xml-encode the contents of the description tag - which will require that the less-than in the above example actually be "double-encoded".  (so just use the CDATA, it's much easier and less error-prone).

Comment: Hi Lee, thanks for the reply. I looked at the table and the columns in question have a coalition of "latin1_swedish_ci" and the default charset is "CHARSET=latin1".

Comment: I've added header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1"); to the document but no luck.

Comment: have you tried different RSS readers?  Is it possible that your reader simply isn't handling the extended charsets properly?  Can you either post a link or post the actual xml that's being problematic?

Comment: Also... you said you "get an error" when trying to add the `<?xml ...>` declaration at the top of the file.  Can you elaborate?  What error do you get?

Comment: In regards to <?xml ...>. What was wrong is that php interpreted "<?" as the beginning of a shorthand php statement. So I followed djn's suggestion. print '<'; print '?xml ...'; and all is fine now. Thanks for trying to help me. Again, I wasn't aware that you were commenting as I wasn't notified by stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Some (partial) suggestions:

The error you get with **`<?xml`** is probably due to the [short_open_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) set to ON in php.ini. When the PHP interpreter reaches the `<?` it understands it as the start of a PHP code block and then throws an error because the next statements are not recognized as PHP. You can change the setting to OFF in php.ini or using [ini_set()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) at the start of the file. Another way around this is to output the `<` separately from the rest, as in:

```
print '<'; print '?xml ...';
```

Next to this I see you're sending `SET NAMES ut8` after you've already issued the `SELECT` statement. This way it has no effect at all on the connection settings relative to the `SELECT` query. `SET NAMES` should indeed be the very first statement issued, before any `INSERT` or `SELECT`. This also assumes that the data that went into the database were UTF-8 to start with. Seeing that the database uses MySQL's factory default charset and collation I suspect that whoever set up the system didn't think about character sets at all, so the UTF-8 assumption might well be wrong.

What you should do is check in detail the script that wrote the original data into the database. If there is a SET NAMES in that script you should use one too when reading the records, if there's not you should avoid it - otherwise you are causing the very charset mismatch you're trying to avoid. Speaking in general terms you can think of the database as a *black box* storage engine: as long as you aren't doing string manipulation inside your SQL code the database will return to you exactly the sequence of bytes that was inserted to it. Plain INSERTs and SELECTs don't care if the bytes they're moving are ASCII, ISO -* or multibyte, they're just blind movers. Thus what you're supposed to use when reading the db are the very same settings used when writing the records: this way you'd get the very same byte sequence originally stored.

The last thing to discover is what character set the data originally stored were. If the data came from a web page form you should check that page, specifically its character set. Browsers have a function to show this (in Firefox: menu View -> Character Encoding, in IE View -> Encoding). When in doubt check the page source for an explicit declaration like `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=xxx">` AND the HTTP headers for a header like `Content-TYpe: text/html; charset=xxx`. If both are present and do not match the HTTP header wins.

The last resource (because it's definitely heavy on the server) is to check the stings returned from the database with [mb_detect_encoding()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) and use this as an input to [iconv()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) to convert it into UTF-8:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8"); /* or any other locale with 'utf8' in it */
$output = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($input), "UTF-8//IGNORE//TRANSLIT", $input);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: what XML error you're talking about? Data that went into database may have any encoding, Mysql can recode! You wrote whole article full of nonsense with just one sensible statement: set names before select. And not a single word about making table charset definition match actual data encoding.

Comment: Sorry if my suggestions didn't make sense to you.

Comment: 1. There are no XML errors mentioned. What I wrote is that the <?xml sequence of characters causes a PHP error when short_open_tags is set to On - because the interpreter reads this as the beginning of a PHP code block. Try for yourself. See http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=16838 for more details.

Comment: 2. MySQL can recode and land you in a bigger mess if you try to change character set without knowing in which charset the actual data currently is. I suppose you aren't suggesting to just guess the actual encoding of the database content and go on a round of converting until one conversion gives the correct results?

More to the point, I understand that the question's author has been asked to add a component (the RSS feed) to an existing website that already has multibyte content stored in latin1 tables - and is currently working this way. Converting that tables would simply break that site.

Comment: djn, What ended up working for me was putting this line in the beginning of the php file: header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=windows-1251");. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the original encoding was in windows-1251 so I added this to the beginning of the php file: header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=windows-1251"); and all dandy now.